# Ionic angular project not Running

Tags: android, npm, ionic-framework, serve

I am new android developer. I am trying to run an old project which ionic-angular.But its not running.My ionic.config.json is as follows:

```
{
"name": "QB",
"integrations": {
"cordova": {}
},
"type": "ionic-angular",
"app_id": ""
}
```

How to make it runnable?

I tried a lot updating all the dependencies which was getting error in command prompt. I was getting error as

Invalid project type: ionic-angular (project config: .\ionic.config.json).

```
    Project type must be one of: angular, angular-standalone, react, vue, custom, vue-vite, react-vite
```

So I changed to angular type...then getting different error

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path E:\Projects\QBMobileApp\qbmobileapp\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed.
E:\Projects\QBMobileApp\qbmobileapp\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.17.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

My package.json is as follows

````
  "name": "QB",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^12.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/base64": "^5.16.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "^5.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/document-viewer": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-x": "^5.19.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/unique-device-id": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "com-badrit-base64": "^0.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "2.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-datepicker": "^0.9.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": "^0.9.13",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": "^1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.3.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.5",
    "ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "js-sha512": "^0.8.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-slick-carousel": "^0.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.0",
    "pod": "^0.9.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "sass-autoprefixer": "^1.0.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.1",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
    "@ionic/lab": "^2.0.6",
    "typescript": ">=4.2.3 <4.4",
    "xcode": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.10.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-datepicker": {},
      "com-badrit-base64": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-uniquedeviceid": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android",
      "Ios"
    ]
  }
}```

>Please anyone help me!
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053174/how-to-run-an-ionic-app-that-was-never-updated-in-five-years

Comment: Try to use older node version

Comment: @denny Using 12.17.1 and 14.0.0,when running command ionic serve i get error as Outdated. Which version i has to use? please share ideas? I need help to run it.

Comment: Also, Can we run ionic 3 projects successfully? Should I first convert it to Ionic 4?

Comment: This project is not updated for 5 years...can i run it in success...what will be steps...please anyone help me?